# Position with Except returns first item {0} and last item {}. Why?

Tags: list-manipulation, traversal

Here is a simple list:

```
l={1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}
```

To get the position of non-zero elements I use `Position` with `Except`:

```
Position[l,Except[0]]
```

Mathematica 9.0.1 returns

```
{{0}, {1}, {3}, {4}, {6}, {8}, {9}, {11}, {13}, {15}, {}}
```

I can't figure out why the first element is `{0}` and the last one is `{}`. If I use `Cases` it works as expected:

```
Cases[l,Except[0]]

{1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `{0}` represents the head of the expression.  For example,

```
l[[0]]

(* ==> List *)
```

About `{}`, the docs say

> A part specification `{}` returned by `Position` represents the whole of *expr*.

You get these results because `Position` searches the expression at all levels.  To get what you were looking for, use

```
Position[l, Except[0], {1}, Heads -> False]
```

to search only [at level 1](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LevelsInExpressions.html) and to ignore heads.

---

To see what the results returned by `Position` mean, you can use `Extract`.  `Extract` supports all part specifications returned by `Position`, including `{}`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It may be worth adding that the traversal is depth-first, head before elements, *but* the entire expression is considered last, not first. This would explain the ordering of the results.

Comment: Or, perhaps, `Position[l, Except[0, _?NumericQ]]` == `Position[l, Except[0, _Integer]]`