# Accessing a list element with a variable as index

Tags: list-manipulation

i'm trying to retrieve an index to a variable and then using that variable to access the list.

The (simplified) code:

```
myList = {1, 5};
minElement = Position[myList, Min[myList]];
myList[[minElement]]
```

I get this error:

```
Part::pkspec1: The expression {{1}} cannot be used as a part specification.
```

The whole idea is to access other lists as well using the minElement index.

This seems like an easy question but i just can't find help about it.

Comment: The results of `Position` are to be used with `Extract`. E.g. `Extract[myList, minElement]`

Comment: Thanks Edmund, this seems to work!

Comment: @Emiliano I've found that frustrating, too. As @Edmund pointed out, `Extract` is the way to go. But in some cases I've gone for `myList[[#]] & @@@ minElement` instead, which gives the same answer.

Comment: If you just need the position of the minimum, you could use `Ordering[]`.

Comment: [115226](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115226/5478)

Comment: Related: [(21723)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21723/121)

Answer (score 0):

It's a formatting problem. maybe use, in a non-elegant way

```
myList = {1, 5};
minElement = Position[myList, Min[myList]][[1]][[1]];
myList[[minElement]]
```

which returns

```
1
```

as expected